# Availability/Reliability monitoring of SAML-enabled site

Tags: saml

We are running PingFederate to enable access to a number of external application using internal authentication information (so kinda sorta SSO).

There are methods for determining whether the PF service is up and accepting requests generally.

But I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how to do authentication testing in a way we can encapsulate it for, e.g. nagios.

(Phantomjs doesn't work or at least hasn't worked out for us.  I'm hoping folks will have another approach to point us towards.)

Thank you.

Comment: What version of PingFed?

Comment: We are running version 7.0.1.

Comment: would you mind commenting on http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/21958/why-a-proposal-for-identity-access-management-makes-sense ? thanks!